# python unit testing for my password validation code

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, tdd

I have this functional code:

```
class PasswordChecker(object):

 passwords = ["aD23"]

 def check(self, passwords):
     if not passwords:
         raise NameError('You have not entered any password')
     else:
         pass
```

And this test code:

```
import unittest

from app.passwordchecker import PasswordChecker

class TestPasswordChecker(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.pswd = PasswordChecker()

  def test_password_checker_raises_nameerror_for_noargs(self):
    self.assertRaises(NameError, self.pswd.check, [])
```

I expect that when the test is made to fail by replacing `[]` with `[items]` in `self.assertRaises()`, it should throw a `NameError - You have not entered any password`. However, it throws a different error meaning my code has a problem. Please help

Comment: Isn't that the expected result?  `check` doesn't do anything `if passwords`, and raises a `NameError` `if not passwords`.  If the list in your assert has values, then `passwords` will be truthy, and thus not raise an error.

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the test code so that it produces an NameError with the argument i have given it i.e 'You have not....? You'll see my issue.

Comment: When I ran this test, it passed.

Comment: Yeah it passes, but now make it fail according to how it has been defined to fail

Comment: When I pass `['a']` instead of `[]`, the test fails.  Could you be more clear about what you expect to happen?

Comment: Please, edit the first code block. Its indentation is off. Everything bellow `class` needs to be moved to the right. I am sure it's not part of the problem, just a copy/paste/format. Unfortunately that edit is too small for the system to allow me to suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing seems correct:

```
self.assertRaises(NameError, self.pswd.check, [])
```

You call `check` with empty list `not passwords` is `True` and `NameError` is raised. That is expected behavior as far as the test is concerned and all is well.

Now if you've changed the line to for instance:

```
self.assertRaises(NameError, self.pswd.check, ['123'])
```

You would see:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_password_checker_raises_nameerror_for_noargs (test_check.TestPasswordChecker)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/so/test_check.py", line 10, in test_password_checker_raises_nameerror_for_noargs
    self.assertRaises(NameError, self.pswd.check, ['123'])
AssertionError: NameError not raised
```

---

Because the method ran, and returned `None`, but the test states it expected `NameError` exception to be raised.

As is, your test could look like this:

```
...
def test_password_checker_raises_nameerror_for_noargs(self):
    self.assertRaises(NameError, self.pswd.check, [])

def test_password_checker_returns_none_with_args(self):
    self.assertIsNone(self.pswd.check(['123']))
...
```

For no args, we expect `NameError` to be raised. With passed argument, we expect `None` to be returned.

---

Side note: [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) has a usual meanings of trying to use unknown variable. Perhaps `ValueError` would be more appropriate. Or you may want to define your own exception.

Comment: I just noted I was failing the test in the wrong way and that's why I got mixed up. I was supposed to change the exception to any other built-in exception( eg TypeError) for NameError to be raised. Anyway thank you.